# Getting "Needs Repair" error in OpenXML PPTX Construction, XML variable not found in code

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm creating a PPTX from scratch using OpenXML in asp.net C#, replacing a 3rd party package.  I create the PresentationDoc in a memory stream, export it in a zip.  Works fine with no slides. When I add a slide, and compare unrepaired (left side) with repaired (right side), I get the comparision shown in the image. For the most part it seems like a fairly straightforward issue of how the SlideParts are named.

For example unrepaired has:
ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout.xml
while the repaired has
ppt/slidelayouts/slideLayout1.xml (with an extra "1").

Yet a global match whole word, match case find in the source code cannot find "slideLayout", which shows up on the left side of the compare.

So I'm wondering if this has something to do with PowerPoint versions  or something else that would not show up my source code. I'm on Office 360. The SDK tool version is 2.5.5631.0.

Or...I have no idea.

Any suggestions on further diagnosis would be appreciated.[image: File comparision]